# add icon to UITextField with rubymotionquery

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

Is it possible to add an icon to to a uitextfield in rmq. If so how can we implement it.

I want to achieve something like this

[image]

The documentation for rmq has not mentioned about images in for UITextFieldStylers.

Update :
For those who might find this useful, I have implemented it as follows with jamon's recommendation.

Screen

```
    @email = rmq.append(UITextField, :email_field) do |q|
         q.append(UIImageView, :password_image)
    end
```

Stylesheet

```
    def password_image(st)
        st.image =  image.resource('image-name')
        //add margin etc inside frame
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend just adding a `UIImageView` to the left of the `UITextField` and positioning it there. Keep it simple.